# WebKit .NET working with cache, cookies and touch support

Tags: c#, webkit

I want to use [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) webbrowser in my application. I didn't find any information about working with cache and cookies on webkit website. Is there any way to clear cache/cookies and how to disable/enable cookies?
I want to use this control in WPF application and want to create zooming and panning functionality with multi-touch support. Does this webkit browser support it from the box? If it's not is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like a dead project, not sure if it's a good idea to use it. Or if it's the same as https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet, then I'm taking my words back.

Comment: It seems to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Essential Objects" are what I'm using. I've tried them all, and only this project turned out to the production ready.